# Epidemiology question, comparing exposures

Tags: self-study, biostatistics, epidemiology

So I'm taking one of those online Epi classes and I'm not sure how to solve this type of problem. I know its probably simple. Any guidance would be appreciated! I didn't include the 2x2 table because I can do the math, I just don't know where to start...

> assume the exposure was measured with 70% sensitivity and 60% specificity for
>   all participants. What is the relative risk of disease X comparing obese and non­obese individuals based on the misclassified data. Characterize the comparison of the true and misclassified relative risk estimates in this study

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this question is trying to get at is the inaccuracy of the exposure.

For example, if you have:

Exposed = 100

Unexposed = 67

Then with the given sensitivity and specificity, some of the unexposed belong in the exposed, and vice versa. The question wants you to calculate the RR before and after this reshuffling.